# Fail of export of unchanged view due to unexpected error reported by Excel

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, view, export

A view, which has several times successfully been exported to Excel suddenly  fails due to unexpected error reported by Excel.

Creating a new view omitting some fields solves the problem, however next day on that same renewed view, the same export failed apparently on same fault reported by Excel (unexpected error).
Same fix kan be done (new view, selected fields) but this will again fail on following day on same Excel fault. We have not encountered this error on  other SharePoint lists/views.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried from the excel to export the table as a SharePoint List? This type of errors are common when there is some column mismatch with the SharePoint Columns. Pay attention to the columns you created, maybe there are calculated column?